# How to use local Apple M1 GPU in a Colab note in a local run time

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory, apple-m1

Hi I'm new to Colab and deep learning.
I'm practising a piece of Colab code (from the web) in which it imports a bunch packages and checks for GPU access.

```
!nvcc --version
!nvidia-smi 

import os, shutil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cellpose import core, utils, io, models, metrics
from glob import glob

use_GPU = core.use_gpu()
yn = ['NO', 'YES']
print(f'>>> GPU activated? {yn[use_GPU]}')
```

Now I would like to run this locally on my Mac M1 pro and am able to connect the colab to local run time. The problem becomes how can I access the M1 chip's GPU?

Running the same code will only give me :

```
zsh:1: command not found: nvcc
zsh:1: command not found: nvidia-smi
```

Which kinda make sense since I dont have nvidia-smi on M1....

Comment: Why did you put those two commands there then?

Comment: M1 chip does not have TPU

Comment: @Siguza sorry should have been more clear on that. I was just playing with a Collab notebook from the web, so I want to run the notbook locally on my machine and now the challenge is about the GPU